# Pyramid pattern: won't work and when run and crashes shortly after... Any ideas?

Tags: java

The code I wrote for a homework just won't work, it would end up crashing my IntelliJ IDEA. Tried it on Eclipse and does the same thing. I can't figure out why my code doesn't work... Can you help me figure it out?

```
import java.util.*;

public class mainClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("how many rows do you want");
        int rows = s.nextInt();

        int spaces;

        System.out.print("what character do you want");
        char ch = s.next().charAt(0);

        for(int count = 1; count<= rows; count++) {
            for(spaces = rows -1; spaces<=rows; spaces--) {
               System.out.print(" ");
            }

            for(int stars =1; stars<=rows; stars= stars + 2) {
                System.out.print(ch);
            }

            System.out.println("");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `for(spaces = rows -1; spaces<=rows; spaces--)` looks like an (almost) infinite loop to me. It will end after about 4 billions of iterations due to `int` underflow and I guess you didn't wait long enough.

Comment: im new to java, how is this an infinite loop?

Comment: @ShreyJoshi Dukeling wasn't suggesting that as an answer - he was suggesting that as a way to find out what's going wrong.

Comment: Look at this loop again: `for(spaces = rows -1; spaces<=rows; spaces--)`. If `rows` is 5, it will count 4, 3, 2, 1, 0, -1, -2, ..., and so on for a *very* long time. Perhaps you meant `spaces >= 0`?

Comment: alright let me try this

Comment: ok so now it shows me the following pattern
     xxx
     xxx
     xxx
     xxx
     xxx
when I enter x as the char

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with your second for loop:

```
for(spaces = rows -1; spaces<=rows; spaces--)
```

This will set `spaces` to `rows - 1` and then keep looping while `spaces` is less than `rows`, which will always be `true` because `spaces` only ever gets smaller. I expect what you meant was more along the lines of

```
for(spaces = rows -1; spaces > 0; spaces--)
```

Comment: "always true" is not exactly correct. Value will eventually reach `MIN_VALUE`, and roll over to `MAX_VALUE`, and the loop will end.

Comment: I got it! But another problem persists, I cant get to make the code work properly, it doesnt print what I want it to...

Comment: @Andreas You're right, although for this case I don't think the difference between an infinite loop and a nearly-infinite loop is a huge difference, since it causes the IDE to crash either way.

Comment: @ShreyJoshi That's good to hear! It's hard to know what exactly you're trying to print from your question, but if my answer solved your main problem then be sure to mark it as accepted :)

Comment: @MatthewSchlachter it would earlier tell me to come back after 5 minutes to mark your answer, seems like I'm late! Thank you!